# Регулярные выражения PHP. Заменить маркеры в тексте на тэги

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида `Просто _обычная_ строка`.
Нужно привести её к виду `Просто <b>обычная</b> строка`.
Т.е. вместо подчёркиваний использовать тэг `<b>` открывающийся и закрывающийся.
Как это сделать наиболее простым способом на PHP?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону preg_replace(). Я написал бы пример, если бы ПК был под рукой. В мануале, кстати, есть примеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вариант будет не лучшим, но должен работать, пробуйте. Правда недостаток, что нельзя внутри строки использовать "_".

```
preg_replace('/_([^_]+)_/u', '<b>$1</b>', 'Просто _обычная_ строка');
```